# "return" outside function - Python

Tags: python, function, return

I'm having a problem with this function. 
When I try run the code, pop-up a message 'return' outside function.

Thanks.

```
def find_details(id2find):
    surfistas_f = open("surfing_data.csv")
    for each_line in surfistas_f:
        s={}
        (s['id'], s['nome'],s['pais'],s['media'],s['prancha'],s['idade'])= each_line.split(";")
        if id2find == int(s['id']):
            surfistas_f.close()
            return(s)
surfistas_f.close()
return({})

lookup_id=int(input(" Entre com a identificação do surfista: "))
surfer = find_details(lookup_id)

if surfer:
    print("ID:           " + surfer['id'])
    print("Nome:         " + surfer['nome'])
    print("País:         " + surfer['pais'])
    print("Média:        " + surfer['media'])
    print("Prancha:      " + surfer['prancha'])
    print("Idade:        " + surfer['idade'])
```

Comment: The file close and return statements are wrongly indented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take care of the code format.
You need 4 additional space before these 2 lines:

```
surfistas_f.close()
return({})
```

Comment: More precisely, it needs to have the same indentation as the lines above.

Comment: According to PEP8 spaces are preferred over tabs. http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces

Comment: @Kroltan: 1 tab would be a SyntaxError in Python 3, since the rest of the code uses spaces.

Comment: @Wooble You're right, it did that the whole time. I just thought SO converted tabs to spaces.

Comment: @IanAlud I disagree completely with that statement. Tabs reduce filesize and offer a more flexible code display (most editors allow to change the tab's size), not to mention text navigating is much faster (tabs just need one arrow key press to go around).

Comment: Yes, thanks. Damn indents. =)

Comment: @Kroltan: feel free to be the 100th or so person to try to change PEP 8...

Answer (score 3):

`return({})` is outside of the function `find_details`. You just need to indent it, like so:

```
def find_details(id2find):
    surfistas_f = open("surfing_data.csv")
    for each_line in surfistas_f:
        s={}
        (s['id'], s['nome'],s['pais'],s['media'],s['prancha'],s['idade'])= each_line.split(";")
        if id2find == int(s['id']):
            surfistas_f.close()
            return(s)
    surfistas_f.close()
    return({})

lookup_id=int(input(" Entre com a identificação do surfista: "))
surfer = find_details(lookup_id)

if surfer:
    print("ID:           " + surfer['id'])
    print("Nome:         " + surfer['nome'])
    print("País:         " + surfer['pais'])
    print("Média:        " + surfer['media'])
    print("Prancha:      " + surfer['prancha'])
    print("Idade:        " + surfer['idade'])
```

Comment: Right! Thanks, Gezim. I'm getting used with the indents.

Answer (score 2):

White space and indentation is very important in Python. Python doesn't use braces like other languages so the way it identifies what lines are part of what is via indentation. For example this simple function:

```
def print_nums(num):
    for i in range(num):
        print(i)
```

can be thought of this way if Python used braces (I shudder at the thought):

```
def print_nums(num): 
{
    for i in range(num): 
    {
        print(i)
    }
}
```

The results of this method would change dramatically if we changed it to:

```
def print_nums(num):
        for i in range(num):
        print(i)
```

which would be as shown with braces:

```
def print_nums(num): 
{
        for i in range(num):
        {
        }
        print(i)
}
```

So making sure everything is indented properly is very important in Python. So specifically for your method return is indented to the same level as the method name which mean the Python interpreter will think of it as being outside the method. You can't use the keyword `return` outside of a method/function so that is why you are seeing the error you are seeing. However you would see some unexpected results had you used `print()` or somehting else at the end.

I would also suggest using Python's `with` statement for opening the file, it handles closing and opening the file for you:

```
with open('surfing_data.csv') as sufista_s:
    do_stuff()
```

Comment: Right. Tnks for your response!